# How to set certain bits? - in Hexadecimal?

Tags: beagleboneblack, i2c

I am now trying for some time to set certain bits in a certain register of a MPU-6050 sensor. In particular I would like to change the accleration sensitivity from the default value of +-2g to +-4g.

According to the Register Map Data sheet of this sensor ([see page 15](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiSxLKW1YLPAhVB6RQKHTR4C9wQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.olimex.com%2FProducts%2FModules%2FSensors%2FMOD-MPU6050%2Fresources%2FRM-MPU-60xxA_rev_4.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFl1UxQ8UxAG1Yg5wIsBPBmZilsUw)) it says I have to change the AFS_SEL value and in my case (+-4g) I have to set Bit 3 to one. Right so far?

So now I am using a Beagle Bone Black that is connected to my sensor. And I can see all the values of the registers if I simply type:

> i2cdump -y 1 0x68

Now I want to set a value in register 1C which is the register specifing the Accleration Sensitivity.

Therefore I used:

> i2cset -y 1 0x68 0x1c 0x01

But according to some tests the 0x01 is wrong. This does not set Bit 3 to one.
I also saw: [here](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/0x00-0x01-0x02-nxnn) that if I want to set bit 3 to one I would have
1000 which is in hexadecimal: 0x08. So I also tried:

> i2cset -y 1 0x68 0x1c 0x08

But it also did not worked. That is why I am a little bit confused.

Hope you can help me!
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the datasheet you refer to, the AFS_SEL field is addressed through bits 3 and 4 of register 0x1C. To set AFS_SEL to 1, you'd write 0x08 to register 0X1C, so your last command is correct:

```
i2cset -y 1 0x68 0x1c 0x08
```